# Copy multiple excel cells into one

Tags: excel, copy-paste

I have lots of Excel data, whereby there are many records which i need to consolidate into one cell.

I know that if I copy text with a carriage return character it will automatically go to new cells, AND that if you paste that same text into the formula bar, it paste's the records into that same cell, keeping the carriage return character, however I am wanting to copy multiple Excel cells then somehow paste them into a single cell.

I know I can paste into a text editor then paste using method above, however my intention is to get something really quick and effective.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `=CONCTENATE(A1,B2,C1,etc)` or `=A1 & B1 & C1 & etc`

Comment: I was hoping to perform the action as quick as the copy-paste function...

Comment: This is probably the fastest way I could think of (short of VBA): http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/13/combine-text-values-quick-tip/